# Grep according to column value in file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

How can I filter out all the rows in a csv file where column number 2 equals to `5`, with the help of awk?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
awk '$2=5' filename
```

Comment: grep is a utility not just searching a file, this question is clearly just about awk

Comment: @JID Will update the question with your input.

Comment: `awk '$2 == 5' FS=, filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After certain permutations and combinations, I found the following query gave the best answer:

`awk -F, '{ if ($2 == '5') print $0 }' filename`

The same query with the 5 *without* quotation marks gave me a blank result.

Comment: Then you must have some problems with the data itself, it sounds quite weird.

Comment: The single quotes around the 5 in this solution are irrelevant, and awk sees exactly the same script whether they are present or not...unless you are using a very unusual shell.

Answer (score 3):

`$2=5` sets `$2` to `5`. To check equality, use `==`:

```
awk '$2==5' filename
       ^^
```

Comment: ...and will be true for every record because `5` is true.

Comment: Yes and no: it will print all the columns, yes, but because the assignation `$2=5` returns True.

Comment: The _assignment_ would "return false" if you changed `5` to `0` though.

Comment: Interesting! You are right. I thought it would act according to the result of the *assignment* (thanks) itself (if it could be done or not). I checked for references in `man awk` and couldn't find anything. So setting to anything false (0, 0.0, "") will have this behaviour.

Comment: This solution gave me a blank output for some reason. However, I just tried the following and it worked. Could someone explain why and how?

`awk -F, '{ if ($2 == '5') print $0 }' filename`

The same query with the 5 without quotation marks gave me a blank result too.

Comment: @Shalapolia because you needed to set the field separator. So `awk -F, '$2==5' file` should make it. And in case some string problems happen, double quote `5` --> `"5"`.

Comment: @fedorqui Can you give an example of how a string problem would occur, as i used to think this but i have never seen it actually cause a problem ?

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you very much! You have been of great help.

Comment: @JID in fact... none, I also thought that but after some testing I noticed there is no difference here between `$2=="5"` and `$2==5`.